# SQL Server CASE returns NULL even when there are values

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, case-when

Below is my sample Query. When I run the query the PreviousTotalQuantity returns null even there are data with in the date range.

```
SELECT
    p.ActualId,
    p.Name,
    p.QTYONHAND AS OnHand,
    p.PRICE AS DistCost,
    SUM(soi.Quantity) AS PresentTotal,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN soi.MASSCHDSHIPDATE > '2014-3-1' AND
            soi.MASSCHDSHIPDATE < '2014-6-1' THEN soi.Quantity
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS PreviousTotalQuantity
FROM 
    sysdba.PRODUCT p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sysdba.SALESORDERITEMS soi
        ON p.PRODUCTID = soi.PRODUCTID
WHERE 
    soi.MASSCHDSHIPDATE > '2015-3-1' AND 
    soi.MASSCHDSHIPDATE < '2015-6-1'
GROUP BY p.PRODUCTID, p.ACTUALID, p.NAME, p.QTYONHAND, p.PRICE
```

I need also to pull the data from the previous year with the given date.

Comment: The date format you're using could cause problems depending language settings, you should always use YYYYMMDD.

Comment: You have table SALESORDERITEMS in outer join, but since you're using it in where clause, it will not be outer joined. Move the date range into the outer join if you need to have an outer join, but still if you're only fetching 2015, you don't get 2014 in the case

Answer (score 0):

Because your years are not in sync in select (2014) and where (2015) part

**Edit**

```
SELECT
    p.ActualId,
    p.Name,
    p.QTYONHAND AS OnHand,
    p.PRICE AS DistCost,
    SUM(soi.Quantity) AS PresentTotal,
    ISNULL(prev.TotalQty, 0) AS PreviousTotalQuantity
FROM 
    sysdba.PRODUCT p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sysdba.SALESORDERITEMS soi
        ON p.PRODUCTID = soi.PRODUCTID
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQty 
        FROM sysdba.SALESORDERITEMS 
        WHERE PRODUCTID = p.PRODUCTID 
            AND MASSCHDSHIPDATE > '2014-03-01' AND MASSCHDSHIPDATE < '2014-06-01'
    ) AS prev
WHERE 
    soi.MASSCHDSHIPDATE > '2015-03-01' AND 
    soi.MASSCHDSHIPDATE < '2015-06-01'
GROUP BY p.PRODUCTID, p.ACTUALID, p.NAME, p.QTYONHAND, p.PRICE, prev.TotalQty
```

Comment: Is there any way to pull the data from that years? I need to pull the data from the previous year.

Comment: It is not the issue of the `case`, but the data you filtered out is current year, the result always be null or 0 (if you fix that as Dark Knight's answer). Correct your query by using sub-query to select previous year

Comment: Hi Eric, I tried your query but for some reason it's not displaying data. It's executing too long.

Answer (score 0):

Don't compare date manually.

Use **between** clause either

```
Declare @PRODUCT table
(
Name varchar(50),
Date datetime,
Quantity int
)

INSERT INTO @PRODUCT VALUES ('Nikunj','2014-3-1',20)
INSERT INTO @PRODUCT VALUES ('Nikunj','2014-6-1',40)
INSERT INTO @PRODUCT VALUES ('Nikunj','2014-9-1',60)
INSERT INTO @PRODUCT VALUES ('JayDeep','2014-3-1',10)
INSERT INTO @PRODUCT VALUES ('JayDeep','2014-9-1',20)

select Name, sum(Quantity),SUM(Case when Date between '2014-3-1' and '2014-6-1' then Quantity else NULL end) TotalQuantity from @PRODUCT 
where Date between '2014-3-1' and '2014-6-1' group by Name
```

Try this accordingly and do check **year** in the where condition code.

Comment: Actually in your where condition you mentioned year which is 2015 and you are trying to find the data of year 2014. That is why you are not getting any data.

Comment: try to replace this where condition "WHERE soi.MASSCHDSHIPDATE > '2014-3-1' AND  soi.MASSCHDSHIPDATE < '2014-6-1'" in your code

Comment: what I'm trying to accomplish is to compare the previous and present quantity with the given date. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you restrict rows in WHERE statement with year 2015 and because of it there are no rows in result set in year 2014. So you get NULL because of CASE works AFTER WHERE statement.

If you need select current 2015 year and count this field for 2014 you can use this query. I doesn't know if PRODUCTID is unique in sysdba.PRODUCT so I use subquery with DISTINCT. If these fields are unique in PRODUCTS just use `FROM PRODUCTS P` without DISTINCT subquery:

```
SELECT
    p.ActualId,
    p.Name,
    p.QTYONHAND AS OnHand,
    p.PRICE AS DistCost,
    soi2015.SUM_Quantity AS PresentTotal,
    soi2014.SUM_Quantity AS PreviousTotalQuantity
FROM 
    (SELECT  DISTINCT 
             p.ActualId,
             p.Name,
             p.QTYONHAND AS OnHand,
             p.PRICE AS DistCost,        
             FROM sysdba.PRODUCT 
    ) p 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      (SELECT PRODUCTID,SUM(soi.Quantity)  SUM_Quantity
        FROM  sysdba.SALESORDERITEMS
        WHERE (MASSCHDSHIPDATE > '2015-03-01') 
               AND (MASSCHDSHIPDATE < '2015-06-1')
        GROUP BY PRODUCTID
      ) soi2015 ON (p.PRODUCTID = soi2015.PRODUCTID) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      (SELECT PRODUCTID,SUM(soi.Quantity)  SUM_Quantity
        FROM  sysdba.SALESORDERITEMS
        WHERE (MASSCHDSHIPDATE > '2014-03-01') 
               AND (MASSCHDSHIPDATE < '2014-06-1')
        GROUP BY PRODUCTID
      ) soi2014 ON (p.PRODUCTID = soi2014.PRODUCTID)
```